# Connecting to DB2 through ODBC is extremely slow

Tags: database, windows, jdbc, db2, odbc

I am experiencing extremely slow connections to a local DB2 (v9.7 Express-C) database through ODBC on a Windows 7 system (x64). I wrote several test programs, each connecting to a local database for 100 times in a row (without querying) and measuring the time. Results are:

[image: Average time for connection to a local database using different methods]
**C++ x86 DB2/ODBC:** 32bit C++ application, connecting to a local DB2 database via [`CDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dhc1abk.aspx)
**C++ x86 DB2/ODBC:** same as above, but x64 application
**PHP DB2/ODBC:** Connecting to a local DB2 database via [`odbc_connect`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.odbc-connect.php).
**PHP MySQL/ODBC:** Connecting to a local MySQL database via `odbc_connect`.
**JDBC DB2:** Java application, connecting to a local DB2 database using the DB2 JDBC driver.
**JDBC MySQL:** Java application, connecting to a local MySQL database using the MySQL JDBC driver.

My first thought was that something's wrong with my ODBC configuration, but as you can see connecting to a MySQL database through ODBC works like charm. On the other hand, connecting to DB2 with the JDBC driver instead of ODBC works fine too (although it's still a lot slower than MySQL).

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625781/extremely-slow-db2-connectivity-in-java), but it does not apply to me.
Any hints on what might be causing this and how to resolve would be great!

**Supplementary question:** What are common connection times when connecting to a DB2 database through ODBC? Is it normal for the DB2 ODBC driver to be so slow?!

Comment: With this few details it's impossible to give you any meaningful answer, but one thing that you should look at is the database activation. DB2 activates the database upon the first connection and deactivates it when the last connection is closed. Try issuing `ACTIVATE DB <YOURDB>` before your tests.

Comment: That helped! Wow, thanks, I've been struggling with this for days! Post that as an answer and I'll accept. Could you also tell me how I can configure my DB2 instance so that it'll always activate that db after startup? Also, why is connection via JDBC so fast? The JDBC driver cannot possibly activate the database itself, because the user that connects to the database has insufficient privileges.

Comment: Can you provide the connection time values with an activated database

Comment: @AngocA: After issuing `ACTIVATE DB` connection time for PHP DB2/ODBC went down to 0,01390625 seconds on average. JDBC DB2 got a little faster too, but was then slower than connecting through ODBC: 0,035751759 seconds on average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you should look at is the database activation. DB2 activates the database upon the first connection and deactivates it when the last connection is closed. During activation DB2 allocates transaction log files, memory pools, and performs a number of other tasks that take time.

This behaviour does not depend on the type of connection (ODBC or JDBC); the difference you observe might be explained by an extra connection that keeps the database active during your JDBC tests.

Try issuing `ACTIVATE DB <YOURDB>` before your tests, which will keep the database active even in the absence of connections. There is no way to activate databases by default, apart from issuing this command upon the system startup, e.g. from a batch file.